# How did Sylar survive being mortally wounded without getting Claire's regenerative power?

Tags: heroes

As it seems Sylar never had the cellular regeneration ability from Claire until later episodes based on the future, how did Sylar ever survive...

1. ... falling off the stands with Peter Petrelli in the home coming episode?
2. ... getting stabbed by Hiro Nakamura?
3. ... getting shot by Matt Parkman in an early season 1 episode?

I know in later episodes he was patched up by Primatech/The Company, but the wounds were fatal, so the question is how did he survive?

Did he have some undisclosed regeneration ability?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answers are, in order:

1. The implication is that he did not fall. We know that he couldn't fly at that point, nor teleport, so we're left without any good answers. There is some evidence that he could have levitated.
2. He suffered the wound, which was almost fatal. Spirited off by one or more people from the company, he then recuperated after undergoing emergency surgery.
3. <s>Again, some unknown power saved his life other than regeneration. He probably wasn't hit by the bullets, if that matters</s>. He likely used telekinesis (acquired by that point) to deflect or stop the bullets.

[edit] After researching, it seems sumbuddyx is correct. TK was the first power that he absorbed, as seen in a flashback, and it is more than plausible that it accounts for him being uninjured by bullets. On other occasions we specifically saw him use it in that fashion.

Comment: I had thought 1 and 3 would be minimalised by his TK ability, somehow...

Comment: @sumbuddyx TK could certainly account for #3... I don't remember when he acquired it. It's unclear how that could mitigate #1 unless TK is identical to flying though, and the show always made a point to distinguish the two.

Comment: Having just watched "Homecoming" again, my only complaint with #1 is that they clearly showed him unconscious on the gound next to Peter after the fall; if he never actually hit the ground, shouldn't he have chased immediately after Claire?

Answer (score 6):

In the episode ["Once Upon a Time in Texas"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Once_Upon_a_Time_in_Texas) Sylar first meets Charlie Andrews, the young woman with perfect memory and correlation abilities.  Sylar says **"I have a gift, too.  I can see how things work and how to fix them if they're broken."**  This ability let him diagnose and fix Charlie's aneurysm.  This ability should allow Sylar to fix himself as well, assuming he's conscious and able to use his power.  That limitation is why Sylar wanted to have Claire Bennet's regenerative ability, which would allow him recover from much more serious injuries.

Comment: I would like to point out that he was only able to fix Charlie because he had telekinesis at this point. While he might *know* how to fix himself in earlier episodes, he had no skills with which to perform the fixing. But given how fast and loose that show played with its own internal logic, I can't rule out your answer being correct either.

Comment: Good point, but Sylar did have telekinetic power by the time he plummeted from the stands with Peter.  We know because he used it to debrain the (wrong) cheerleader earlier in the episode, and to send debris rocketing toward Peter at the beginning of their confrontation.

Comment: I thought the finger-bonesaw thing was separate from his telekinesis.

Comment: Sylar konked his first victim in the back of the head; he got the TK from him, presumably opening the poor guy's head by other means.

Answer (score 2):

Matt Parkman's bullets clearly hit Sylar and knocked him down, so it wasn't the case that 
Sylar stopped them in time.

I guess you could say that Sylar slowed them with telekinesis, which we know he had, such that they hit him hard enough to knock him down, but not hard enough to penetrate his organs. I don't think this is the case, because the fast mental reflexes required to slow bullets is literally never demonstrated by Sylar again. (For instance, when Hiro stabbed him at the end of Season 1, he had more reaction time than when Matt shot him, but couldn't stop or slow Hiro or the blade). Sylar also accompanied most of his telekinesis with a corresponding hand or arm gesture, which he did not do when Matt shot him.

Sylar was, from the moment of his introduction, probably a real pain to write because he ought to have been unstoppable. He had a huge amount of powers, including a sort of meta-power that allowed him to use the others in the way "worked" best. In theory, he should have been unstoppable (especially after he gained Isaac Mendez's precognition). However, that makes for bad story-telling, so he got taken down sometimes. And then sometimes he got up.

Answer (score 0):

Sylar has incredible control over his abilities compared to the original owners. It's possible that when injured internally he could use his TK to hold a wound together. Kind of like a telekinetic suture. Like putting pressure on an external wound to stem the bleeding. That and the fact that he's essentially a comic book super villain and in the comics no one truly dies.